# What does $E_{x}[f(x,y)]$ mean?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Frankly, the title says it all. In the context of expectations in probability, what does it mean

$$E_{x}[f(x,y)]$$

In the single variable case, $E[f(x)]$ is equal to $\displaystyle \int p(x)f(x)dx$, so I guess it means $\displaystyle \int p(x,y)f(x,y)dx$ (although it also seems possible $\displaystyle \int p(x)f(x,y)dx $) but after searching for a while, I can't confirm this.

Regards

Comment: You might need a $dy$ in the integral.

Comment: By $E_x$ do you mean the conditional expectation with respect to some sigma-algebra (for e.g. $\mathcal{F} = \{A \times \mathbb{R}  \mid A \text{ Borel}\})$?

Comment: @DSeita No, the integral is averaging only over x. Actually, the book where I read this says that "Note that $E_{x}[f(x,y)]$ will be a function of y"

Comment: @ABlumenthal No, x refers to the variable in the integral but I don't know if the probability distribution should be $p(x,y)$ or $p(x)$.

Comment: But using $p(x,y)$ or $p(x)$ ?

Comment: I imagine it should be normalized e.g. like $${\bf E}_x(f(x,y))=\int \frac{p(x,y)}{\int p(\tau,y)d\tau}f(x,y)dx$$ so that expectation preserves constants.

Comment: @anon It could be but do you have some reference?

Comment: see http://math.arizona.edu/~tgk/563/cond_exp.pdf

Comment: @RobertSmith Where did you see this notation?

Comment: @anon Uhm, what page? I can't find it.

Comment: @Did Here: http://www.amazon.com/dp/0387310738/ Page 20

Comment: "Page 20 is not included in this book preview". However, what I could read on pages xi (bottom) and xii (top) raised the hair on my head.

Comment: That's weird, I can see page 19 and 20 in the preview (in amazon.com). Actually, xi (bottom) is pretty much what I was referring to in page 20. I don't mind changes in notation, but I definitely want to know exactly what they mean.

Comment: What happens next?